# Appending one shapefile to another using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, append

I am using ArcGIS 10.6.1.  I have one shapefile with ~5,600 points, and another with ~4,200,000 points.  I would like to combine these as one, then export as a flat text file/CSV.  I've tried using the "Append" tool , and made sure all fields were named / formatted exactly the same, but it is not working.  It says the schema does not match, even though all fields are exactly the same between the 2 shapefiles.

Is the issue that the Object ID fields added by default share duplicative values between the 2 shapefiles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things in the original question, so:

If it is saying it's a schema issue, make sure you set the Schema Type option in the Append Tool to "NO TEST", and then you can check the field mapping section to ensure fields actually are mapped correctly.  Note: differences in fields are not always easily evident; things like having two text fields with the same field name but different field lengths can even cause issues, so being diligent in checking that 2 fields actually match is important.

Another thing is, when dealing with larger datasets like that, I'd suggest doing it all within a File Geodatabase as far as the appends and any data manipulation and then export to your chosen flat file format. Shapefiles don't always scale that large that well, so any time you're working with really large datasets, it always best to avoid the shapefile if possible.

And no, Object IDs shouldn't be the issue as the append tool should auto re-assign new Object IDs for the newly appended in features. That said, it is important to note that the Object ID will be re-assigned, so if you rely on the existing Object IDs for relationships with other datasets (ex: to use in table joins), you will want to ensure you preserve that Object ID either by copying it to a new field before doing the append or using field mapping options to field map the current Object ID into another field as part of the Append tool.

Comment: I forgot to say thank you, John.  When working within the file geodatabase instead of with each individual shapefile, the task was executed seamlessly.

Comment: Also, why do some people edit questions like its an essay or something?  Does it really matter if I capitalize the first letter of each work in the title?  Why would a question be voted down for that?  Guess I'm not in the know of how this works lol

Comment: @AshleyLynnTarver, there was a time on this site where people's questions were getting barely readable, so moderators started editing more. Since then some users have taken it way to an extreme (needlessly in my opinion). But, they probably aren't voting down for formatting issues like that. On a question like yours, inconsiderate users are likely voting it down because it's an issue they have no experience with. And since they can't personally answer it you must not have worded the question correctly, since if only you'd worded it correct, they could have answered it. Sorry for that happening

Comment: No worries. John, thank you for your help!